# MysqL php thread security

Tags: php, thread-safety

I have a database that I access all the time.
But the problem is that if I access the database in 2 threads at the same time (with a 0.001 ms delay), then the database will reply to both threads with the same values (although it should reply to two threads with different values).

I was told to read about thread-safe collections. But I still did not understand what exactly I was talking about.
Is there a PHP solution for this?

Comment: What are you trying to do here please post some example data, expected results based on the example data, some PHP code..

Comment: You probably aren’t looking for thread-specific things, that is a red herring. Instead, look into database/query atomicity, ACID, and potentially locks and mutexes.

Comment: We have a python script that sends requests to our key warehouse and gets the key from there
This key must be retrieved once, after that it is moved to the table of inactive keys and the previous key is deleted

The python script runs in threads and some requests are sent at the same millisecond
Because of this, the response from these two queries is the same key and should be different

We have mysql on the server
At this point we have set TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL - SERIALIZABLE

But the problem persists